# do i treat (y) as a variable or as a constant when differentiating dy/dx

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, partial-derivative

I want to find $\left(\dfrac{dy}{dx}\right)$ for :  $x^3 +y^3=6xy$ ,i don't understand when diff $(y^3)$ do i treat it like a constant or do i treat it like a term?

Comment: Use chain rule. Search "implicit differentiation"

Comment: $\mathrm{d}(y^3) = 3 y^2 \mathrm{d} y$ is always true whether $y$ is constant or not. (but in a setting where it's constant, $\mathrm{d}y = 0$)

Comment: @Hurkyl: What about for a shape defined by, say, $xy = 0$. At the point $(x, y) = (0, 3)$, what does dy mean? Unless you want to allow equality between infinite values, or you want to treat dy as a 1-form or something (which is likely well beyond OP's level), I'm not sure there's a reasonable sense in which $d(y^3) = 3y^2 dy$, perhaps because I don't know what your "d" means here.

Comment: @JohnHughes: The notion of differential is robust; whatever way you make sense of $\mathrm{d}y$, $\mathrm{d}(y^3)$ will be given by that formula! Today I do have differential forms in mind as a way to formalize it (which, in Euclidean space, is basically the same thing as [this elementary formalization of differentials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_of_a_function)), but when I learned calculus, the meaning I gave the notation was simply "the derivative with respect to something I haven't decided on".

Comment: @Hurkyl: That last description does require that this derivative *exist* (which is why in my answer I mention the assumption of a differentiable function $Y$, a key point in the implicit function theorem). Consider something like the Peano curve. There's no parameterization of that for which a derivative ever makes sense (except for a constant path). I'm reluctant to embrace any notation that suggests otherwise, but I'm certainly aware of the convenience of doing so, and do it all the time in my "scratch work".

Answer (score 5):

It helps to remember here that you're ASSUMING that there's a function, which I'll call $Y$ to keep things distinct, such that 
$$
x^3 + Y(x)^3 = 6 \cdot x \cdot Y(x)
$$
and since the expressions on the left and right side of the equality both are functions of $x$, you can differentiate them. For the right hand side, for instance, you get 
$$
deriv = 6 Y(x) + 6x Y'(x)
$$
But this is almost always written 
$$
deriv = 6y + 6x \frac{dy}{dx}
$$
completely hiding the dependence of $Y$ on $x$.

Comment: Why neglect the left hand side?  $\frac{d}{dx}(x^3 + y^3) = 3x^2 +3y^2\frac{dy}{dx},$ which is necessary to be able to solve for $dy/dx$ given your differentiation of (only) the right hand side?  i.e. $$3x^2 + 3y^2\frac{dy}{dx} = 6y + 6x \frac{dy}{dx}$$  Now solving for $dy/dx$ is made possible.

Comment: I neglected it so that the OP would have an opportunity to practice. And my answer DID answer the asked question, which was "do I treat y as a constant or not?"

Answer (score 1):

As Zachary Selk commented, the easier way is to use the implicit function theorem.

So, consider the implicit function $$F=x^3 +y^3-6xy=0$$ Compute the partial derivatives $$F'_x=3x^2-6y \qquad \text{and} \qquad F'_y=3y^2-6x$$ Now, apply the implicit function theorem which states that 
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{F'_x}{F'_y}=\frac{2y-x^2}{y^2-2x}$$ The advantage is that, when you take the partial with respect to one variable, all other variables are treated as constants.

Answer (score -1):

Think of it as separating all the elements dependent on x being represented as functions (i.e. assuming those functions differentiable at x) . Then take the limit for each change in function ($\Delta(f(x)$) as $\Delta$x->0 which then will just work as simple fractions instead of lagrange's notation.

$$\lim\limits_{\Delta x \to 0} \frac{\Delta f(x)}{\Delta x}$$

So for the a
g(x) = $x^3$
and h(y) = $y^3$

So it becomes $\frac{\Delta g(x)}{\Delta x}$ + $\frac{\Delta h(y)}{\Delta y} * \frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}$

and taking the limit will give you $\frac{dy}{dx}$

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. Can you please [edit] your post and improve it, in particular the maths formatting? See some tips on [answer], on [formatting help](https://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help) and on writing down equations using [LaTeX / MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020). By the way, take the opportunity to take the [Tour], if you haven't done it already.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion @Ertxiem. Edited.

Comment: Also someone please explain whoever down-voted this. I have edited this to clear up the math part. Any other feedback would be appreciated. Thank you